# Change the value of a text box to its current order in a sortable tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

### **Edit: I have solved this by myself. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145241/change-the-value-of-a-text-box-to-its-current-order-in-a-sortable-tab/145388#145388)**

I have set up a nice sortable table with jQuery and it is quite nice. But now i want to extend it.

Each table row has a text box, and i want i am after is to, every time a row is dropped, the text boxes update to reflect the order of the text boxes. **E.g. The text box up the top  always has the value of '1', the second is always '2' and so on.**

I am using jQuery and the [Table Drag and Drop JQuery plugin](http://www.isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/)

#### Code

**Javascript:**

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#table-2").tableDnD({
      onDrop: function (table, row) {
        var rows = table.tBodies[0].rows;
        var debugStr = "Order: ";
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
          debugStr += rows[i].id + ", ";
        }
        console.log(debugStr)
        document.forms['productform'].sort1.value = debugStr;
        document.forms['productform'].sort2.value = debugStr;
        document.forms['productform'].sort3.value = debugStr;
        document.forms['productform'].sort4.value = debugStr;
      },
    });
  }); 
</script>
```

**HTML Table:**

```html
<form name="productform">
  <table cellspacing="0" id="table-2" name="productform">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Product</td>
        <td>Order</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="row1" id="Pol">
        <td><a href="1/">Pol</a></td>
        <td><input type="textbox" name="sort1"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row2" id="Evo">
        <td><a href="2/">Evo</a></td>
        <td><input type="textbox" name="sort2"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row3" id="Kal">
        <td><a href="3/">Kal</a></td>
        <td><input type="textbox" name="sort3"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row4" id="Lok">
        <td><a href="4/">Lok</a></td>
        <td><input type="textbox" name="sort4"/></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hardnrg in #jquery ended up solving it for me.

It involved adding an id="" to each input:

```
<form name="productform">
    <table cellspacing="0" id="table-2" name="productform"> 
        <thead>
            <tr><td>Product</td>    <td>Order</td></tr> 
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr class="row1" id="Pol">  <td><a href="1/">Pol</a></td>   <td><input id="Pol_field" type="textbox" name="sort1"/></td>    </tr>
            <tr class="row2" id="Evo">  <td><a href="2/">Evo</a></td>   <td><input id="Evo_field" type="textbox" name="sort2"/></td>    </tr>
            <tr class="row3" id="Kal">  <td><a href="3/">Kal</a></td>   <td><input id="Kal_field" type="textbox" name="sort3"/></td>    </tr>
            <tr class="row4" id="Lok">  <td><a href="4/">Lok</a></td>   <td><input id="Lok_field" type="textbox" name="sort4"/></td>    </tr>
        </tbody> 
    </table>
</form>
```

And add this js to the OnDrop event:

```
for (var i=0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    $('#' + rows[i].id + "_field").val(i+1);
}
```

Easy peasy!

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm..
I think you want to do something like this:

```
$("input:text", "#table-2").each( function(i){ this.value=i+1; });
```

The $().each() function's info is here: http://docs.jquery.com/Core/each